# How to fill textboxes when the data are retrieving from two tables?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to retrieve data from two tables to fill the textboxex when I'm click the Button Print but I got an error saying:

> Column 'UID' in where clause is ambiguous.

I have two tables named tableProducts with Columns ProductID, ProductName, and ProductPrice AND tableQuantity with columns QuantityID and AvailableQuantity.

Here are my codes.

SqlClientConn.Open()

```
    Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT ProductName,ProductPrice FROM tableProducts INNER JOIN tableQuantity ON tableProducts.ProductID = tableQuantity.QuantityID WHERE ProductID='" & txtid.Text & "'"

    Dim mySqlDataAdapter As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(SQLString, SqlClientConn)<br>
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds)

    If ds.Tables(&quot;tableProducts&quot;).Rows.Count > 0 Then

txtname.Text = ds.Tables(ProductName).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
txtprice.Text = ds.Tables(ProductPrice).Rows(0).Item(1).ToString()
txtquantity.Text = ds.Tables(AvailableQuantity).Rows(0).Item(2).ToString()

 End If
    SqlClientConn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The ProductID exist in both table in tableProducts and tableProducts so it says

Column  in where clause is ambiguous

```
SELECT ProductName,ProductPrice FROM tableProducts INNER JOIN tableQuantity ON tableProducts.ProductID = tableQuantity.QuantityID WHERE ProductID='" & txtid.Text & "'"
```

Use alias for the tableProducts 
Try this query

```
SELECT ProductName,ProductPrice FROM tableProducts INNER JOIN tableQuantity ON tableProducts.ProductID = tableQuantity.QuantityID WHERE tableProducts.ProductID='" & txtid.Text & "'"
```

or

```
SELECT a.ProductName,a.ProductPrice FROM tableProducts a INNER JOIN tableQuantity ON tableProducts.ProductID = tableQuantity.QuantityID WHERE a.ProductID='" & txtid.Text & "'"
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think a `DataReader` would be simpler. No SQL Injection here.

```
Dim sql = SELECT ProductName,ProductPrice FROM 
          tableProducts INNER JOIN 
          tableQuantity ON tableProducts.ProductID = tableQuantity.QuantityID
          WHERE tableProducts.ProductID=@pId"
sqlCom = New SQLCommand(sql, SqlClientConn)
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pId", txtid.Text)
SqlClientConn.Open()
Using reader As SQLDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader
  If reader.HasRows Then
    While reader.Read
      txtname.Text = reader("ProductName").ToString
      txtprice.Text = reader("ProductPrice").ToString
      txtquantity.Text = reader("TableQuantity.AvailibleQuantity").ToString
    End While
  End If
End Using
```

Comment: there's an error at this line sir <br> txtquantity.Text = reader("TableQuantity.AvailibleQuantity").ToString <br> saying: Could not find specified column in results: tblSample.Status

Comment: I was not sure about the related table for this. Can check the reader and see if you can see if it has the name for this field?